# How to make select and datetime elements populated by data when Updating in CRUD

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form which takes values from model, I want to edit it in Update operation in CRUD. The problem is, rails doesnt populate SELECT and DATETIME-LOCAL elements with their data from model. All other (company, description) elements work. i.e they are prefilled with data.

I tried to use different helpers (select, datetime) in form_with, but either they dont work, or they dont fit my requirements

```rb
<%= form_with model: @request, html: {id: "form-pass-request"} do |form| %>
<div class="splitcontentleft">
    <p>
        <%= form.label 'Type of request' %><br>
        <%= form.select :request_type, options_for_select([["choose type", "choosetype"],["Guest request", "guest"], ["Prop request", "prop"]]), {}, {id: "pass-type"} %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= form.label 'company' %><br>
        <%= form.text_field :company %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= form.label 'purpose ' %><br>
        <%= form.text_area :purpose %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= form.label 'accompanying_id' %><br>
        <%= form.select :accompanying_id, principals_options_for_select(User.all, @request.accompanying_id), {}, id: 'accompanying_person' %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= form.label 'place ' %><br>
        <%= form.text_area :place %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= form.label 'description ' %><br>
        <%= form.text_area :description %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Date from</label>
      <br>
      <input type="datetime-local" id="date-from" name="date_from">
      <input type="hidden" id="date-from-hidden" name="date_from_hidden">
    </p>
    <div class = "date_to">
      <p>
        <label>Date to</label>
        <br>
        <input type="datetime-local" id="date-to" name="date_to">
        <input type="hidden" id="date-to-hidden" name="date_to_hidden">
      </p>
    </div>
    <p>
        <%= form.submit 'Edit request' , id: 'edit-button', name: 'edit_button'%>
    </p>
</div>
    <% end %>
```

I expect to 2 SELECTS and 2 DATETIME-LOCALS elements to be prefilled when i go to my edit action. Now, it filled with first (default actions).
Also I use select2select js plugin, but I dont think it might be problem, because Ive turned it off to second select element.

Comment: Why you are not using your syntax `form.your_input` for `date` type ? Because you are using `html_input` instead of `rails` input.

Comment: because i need datetime picker, datetime local which is html totally fits my requirements, the one which rails does provide, have no time option to pick, or datetime select helper isnt comfortable, each select for each element (year, month....)

Comment: Ok, I think you should set a value in Jquery. I don't know what is the  `Select2` `attributes` to set a value in datepicker (maybe `value=` or `data=`etc.). The default value will be the current time if your are create a new object otherwise it will be you your date from your `request` object.

Comment: thx for the advice, but i need the datetime picker, so user could pick date, and time, which is the request's from and to duration range

Comment: I guess it works also with `datetime picker`, just inspect your element and check what attributes is used to set value (where `current_date' is) and then set this value through Jquery.

Comment: If you are using bootstrap, you can add a datetime picker field the rails way and it should have the required values.